# How to rescale the x axis?

Tags: plotting, ticks

Please suggest how to rescale the x axis by `t0`:
  I am trying to plot given the exponential below.

```
t0 = .002;
Plot[(1 - Exp[-t/t0]), {t, 0, .008}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Charting`FindTicks

Using the automatically generated scaled ticks:

```
t0 = .002;
Plot[(1 - Exp[-t/t0]), {t, 0, .008}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`FindTicks[{0, t0}, {0, 1}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

The function `` Charting`FindTicks[{a, b}, {c, d}][min, max] `` generates the major and minor ticks based on the automatically computed minimum and maximum of the values on the axis using the parameters `{a, b}`, `{c, d}` for rescaling.

```
Charting`FindTicks[{0, t0}, {0, 1}][0, .008 ]
```

> {{0., 0}, {0.002, 1}, {0.004, 2}, {0.006, 3},  {0.008, 4},
> {0., "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0004,  "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0008, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0012, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0016, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.002, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.002, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0024, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0028, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0032, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0036, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.004,  "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.004, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0044, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0048, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0052, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0056, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.006, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.006,  "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0064, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0068,  "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0072, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.0076, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
> {0.008, "", {0.005, 0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}}}

Another example:

```
Plot[(1 - Exp[-t/t0]), {t, 0, 5 (.008)}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`FindTicks[{0, t0}, {0, 1}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

**Update 1:** How to use it when `Frame-> True`

```
Plot[(1 - Exp[-t/t0]), {t, 0, .008}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, t0}, {0, 1}], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

> *Can you suggest about, if I want to find the time constant by taking the log of the plot*

Pretending you don't know `t0`, extract the point coordinates from `Plot` output and use `FindFit` or `Solve` to find the scaling parameter:

```
plot = Plot[(1 - Exp[-t/t0]), {t, 0, .008}];
coords = Cases[plot, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]];


a /. FindFit[coords, 1 - Exp[-x/a], {a}, x]
```

> 0.002

```
a /. Quiet @ Solve[(#2 == 1 - Exp[-#/a]), a, Reals][[1]] & @@ coords[[1]]
```

> 0.002

Comment: Thanks@kglr, Does it work for both axis?

Comment: @GopalVerma, my pleasure. It does work for all axes. (In 3D too)

Comment: good. Can u suggest about  , If I want to find the time constant by taking the log of  the plot.

Comment: Also, above ticks does not if use Frame-> True.

Comment: @GopalVerma, please see the updates.

Comment: Thank a lot @ kglr.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you only have to modify your ticks labels:

```
t0 = .002; 
Plot[(1 - Exp[-t/t0]), {t, 0, .008}, PlotRange -> All, 
Ticks -> {Table[{i, (i/t0)}, {i, 0, 0.008, 0.001}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@ Navas, It is sufficient.

Comment: But, It is not working when I use  Frame->True.

Comment: Use `FrameTicks` instead...

Comment: yes, It is working.